# Get position of the item LongClicked in a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` displaying custom views (3 `TextViews` per item); I have just implemented a context menu like such:

```
// in onCreateView
ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

registerForContextMenu(list);
```

and

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    if (v.getId() == R.id.list) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.todo_context_menu, menu);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.edit:
            // your first action code
            return true;
        case R.id.delete:
            // your second action code
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I wish to know which item has been long clicked (its position in the `ListView` would be ideal) in order to edit or delete the right one.

How may that be achieved?

Comment: A simple search goes a long way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18632538/1269953

Comment: I did see this thread, I guess it went over my head

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

   AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
   int index = info.position;

  switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.edit:
        // your first action code
        return true;
    case R.id.delete:
        // your second action code
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you, I will accept your answer asap.